# Having Run time error in using Taglib on 32 bit working fine on 64 bit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, taglib

This error is coming when run on 32 bit . Its an Universal app working fine on 64 bit but not on 32 bit....
I set search header path @executable_path/../Frameworks but it is not working

**ERROR**
dyld: Library not loaded: /TagLib.framework/Versions/1/TagLib
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioData-drsiciozrlbnmtgvcxpircfgpyxa/Build/Products/Debug/AudioData.app/Contents/MacOS/AudioData
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

Seems framework doesn't support arm64 architecture.
There are 2 solutions
1) Find the library that is compiled for arm64 architecture too.
2) Disable arm64 compiling for your target (it will run on arm64 but with backward compatibility)

So to disable arm64 architecture,
1) Click on your project file, Click on your target, open "Build Settings" section, and click on "Architectures" and choose "Other".
[image]

2) Remove ARCHS_STANDART, and add "armv7", "armv7s", "x86" and maybe "i386"
That should look like this
[image]

3) And remove "arm64" from "Valid Architectures"
[image]

After this steps, it should run without problems.